# Is there a Java compiler that disallows multiple classes per file if "The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package ..."?

Tags: java, javac, jls

In general, Java compilers require public, top-level classes to be in a file with a name matching the class name.  There are lots of questions on this site about "class Bar is public, should be declared in a file named Bar.java".

This is mentioned in the JLS in [§7.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-7.html#jls-7.6) as the second optional restriction when storing code in files (instead of a DB):

> If and only if packages are stored in a file system (§7.2), the host system may choose to enforce the restriction that it is a compile-time error if a type is not found in a file under a name composed of the type name plus an extension (such as .java or .jav) if either of the following is true:
>
> - The type is referred to by code in other compilation units of the package in which the type is declared.
> - The type is declared public (and therefore is potentially accessible from code in other packages).

**Are there mainstream compilers that enforce the *first* restriction that classes be in their own file if they're referred to by other files in the package?**

`javac` versions 1.8 and 1.7 don't appear to:

`twotype/TwoType.java`:

```
package twotype;

public class TwoType {}
class Bar {}
```

`twotype/TypeTwo.java`:

```
package twotype;

public class TypeTwo {
  Bar bar;  // Do any compilers throw an error here?
}
```

This compiles fine:

```
$ javac7 -version
javac 1.7.0_80
$ javac7 twotype/*.java
$ 

$ javac8 -version
javac 1.8.0_66
$ javac8 twotype/*.java
$
```

Comment: "In general, Java compilers require top-level classes to be in a file with a name matching the class name." Only public classes, *in general*.

Comment: I don't believe so, but why do you care? Are you worried about getting tied to a particular compiler implementation? Or are you trying to enforce this as a best practice using a compiler?

Comment: @ArtB Worries about portability, yeah.  I saw some code like `TypeTwo.java` above and want to know if it's fine, or if it will bite me in the ass if my build system changes somewhere down the line.

Comment: Even if it was a compiler issue, the resulting binaries (ie `.class`) and its supported by the JVM almost everyone uses (ie Oracle) + OpenJDK so I really wouldn't worry about it.